# How to use extensible-effects and IO?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to rewrite the examples from the [article](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-12-04-24-days-of-hackage-extensible-effects.html) to the new version of the package [extensible-effects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-effects) 1.11.0.0, but I get "Could not deduce ..." when I try to use the lift for IO monad     :(

ghc 7.10.1

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Main where

import Data.Typeable
import Control.Eff
import Control.Eff.Lift

data Log v = Log String v deriving (Functor, Typeable)

log' :: Member Log r => String -> Eff r ()
log' txt = send . inj $ Log txt ()

verboseAddition :: Member Log r => Eff r Int
verboseAddition = do
   log' "I'm starting with 1..."
   x <- return 1

   log' "and I'm adding 2..."
   y <- return 2

   let r = x + y

   log' $ "Looks like the result is " ++ show r
   return r

runLogger :: Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r ([String],a)
runLogger = loop
   where 
     prefixLogWith txt (l,v) = (txt:l, v)
     loop = freeMap
       (\x -> return ([], x))
       (\u -> handleRelay u loop
              $ \(Log txt next) -> fmap (prefixLogWith txt) (loop next))

runIOLogger :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r a
runIOLogger = loop
   where
     loop = freeMap
       return
       (\u -> handleRelay u loop 
              $ \(Log txt next) -> 
                  lift (putStrLn txt)  >>  --  Could not deduce ...    :(
                  loop next)

main:: IO ()
main = --    print $ run $ runLogger verboseAddition -- ok
       runLift (runIOLogger verboseAddition) >>= print
```

> ```
> Could not deduce (extensible-effects-1.11.0.0:Data.OpenUnion.Internal.Base.M emberUImpl
>                     extensible-effects-1.11.0.0:Data.OpenUnion.Internal.Open Union2.OU2
>                     Lift
>                     (Lift IO)
>                     r)
>   arising from a use of `lift'
> from the context (SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r)
>   bound by the type signature for
>              runIOLogger :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r =>
>                             Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r a
>   at src\Main.hs:37:16-72
> In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `lift (putStrLn txt)'
> In the expression: lift (putStrLn txt) >> loop next
> In the second argument of `($)', namely
>   `\ (Log txt next) -> lift (putStrLn txt) >> loop next'
> ```

Comment: Could you write the *whole* error?

Comment: ok. I have included the complete error message in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
runIOLogger :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r a
runIOLogger = freeMap
  return
  (\u -> handleRelay u runIOLogger $ \(Log txt next) -> do
           lift $ putStrLn txt
           runIOLogger next)
```

As well as this:

```
runIOLogger :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r a
runIOLogger = loop
   where
     loop :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => Eff (Log :> r) a -> Eff r a
     loop = freeMap
       return
       (\u -> handleRelay u loop 
              $ \(Log txt next) -> 
                  lift (putStrLn txt)  >>  --  Could not deduce ...    :(
                  loop next)
```

GHC [can't infer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion) polymorphic types for recursive bindings, instead it first infers a type with the assumption that the recursively bound variable is monomorphic, then generalizes the resulting type. This means that type inference only fails if we use different instantiations of a recursive binding. For example, this fails to check:

```
id' a = fst (a, id' (a, a))
```

But this is fine:

```
id' :: a -> a
id' a = fst (a, id' (a, a))
```

I'm pretty sure something like this is the issue here, although I haven't made the effort to find out exactly where does inference grind to a halt.